# Issue with Mongoose Timestamp and epoch conversion to Date()

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose

I have a Mongoose schema with the `timestamp` option set as true.

```
schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
},
{ timestamps: true });
```

Now I have an Android application that gets the timestamp using `System.currentTimeMillis()` which works all well and good and gives me number of milliseconds since UNIX epoch time.

I send this data across to my Node.js / Express server which takes the time and returns only documents created after that particular date.

```
// get all docs
router.get('/api/seekers', function(req, res) {
    Seeker.find({createdAt:{ $gt: new Date(req.query.timestamp) }}, function(err, seekers) {
        if(err)
            res.send(err);
        else 
            res.json(seekers);
    });
});
```

So I send `https://api_url.com/api/seekers?timestamp=1479431351762` as a request to the server.

Now a couple of things happen:

1. I send the value in milliseconds and get this error

   `{"message":"Cast to date failed for value \"Invalid Date\" at path \"updatedAt\"","name":"CastError","kind":"date","value":null,"path":"updatedAt"}`

   After a little bit of investigation, it turns out you need to pass seconds to `Date()`. So,
2. I divide the value by 1000 to get seconds (`req.query.timestamp/1000`). Now I wasn't getting an error, but the query constraint was not working. I'm getting all values since the beginning of time.
3. I moved over to the Mongo shell to check whether the issue persists, to which it turns out it *doesn't* since I can pass the millisecond value to Mongo's Date:

   `> new Date(1479431351762)
   ISODate("2016-11-18T01:09:11.762Z")`

   But if I tried passing the second value to `Date()`, it turns out it *actually was* sending me to the beginning of time:

   `> new Date(1479431351)
    ISODate("1970-01-18T02:57:11.351Z")`

I'm unable to figure this out, what can I do so server request and mongoose correctly processes the timestamp and queries my db?

Comment: Have your tried casting the query string to int as `Seeker.find({createdAt:{ $gt: new Date(parseInt(req.query.timestamp)) }}, function(err, seekers) { ... }`?

Comment: Well, dang. Should've been the first thing I tried. Either way, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any wanderers with the same issue, who might have missed [chridam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122005/chridam%22chridam%22)'s comment, you just need to cast the passed timestamp to `int` before parsing. This works:

`new Date(parseInt(req.query.timestamp))`